# porting wireshark to qnx based system

Tags: wireshark, libpcap, cisco-ios

I am a newbie to industry and as a part of my internship I have been assigned the above project.I have no experience in how to go about porting a particular application to a different OS.

So far,i have tried to understand the basic structure of a component(thats what an application is called IOS-XR) but as far as I can understand,porting wireshark will also require porting the libpcap lib to XR.

Can someone please shed some light as to how should i go about approaching it?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about QNX;

However, I will note that Wireshark has a lot of dependencies on various libraries:

Some examples;

```
libgLib
libgtk
libffi-5
libfontconfig-1
libfreetype-6
libintl-8
libjasper-1
libjpeg-8
liblzma-5
libpixman-1-0
libpng15-15
libtiff-5
libxml2-2
...
```

Are these libraries available on QNX ?

With respect to libpcap:

libpcap is needed for capturing files. If not available, it certainly would need to be ported. I could imagine that this might be a large effort given that presumably the code is presumably quite dependent upon the exact OS capabilities to get access to the network level data.

For information about developing Wireshark (on Windows and *nix) see the
[Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/).